# Are there reasons to use array.forEach() over for...of, when both could be used, in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-6

With [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), is there any reason to continue advocating use of the slightly older `Array.prototype.forEach()`?

A lot of code written in ES6 today contains code such as:

```
let sum = 0;
values.forEach((value) => {
    sum += value;
});
```

In almost all of these situations, an equivalent for..of loop could be used instead:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let value of values) {
  sum += value;
}
```

The more concise versions of the two formats:

```
values.forEach(value => sum += value);
for (let value of values) sum += value;
```

The for..of format works not only with `Array` objects but other iterables as well and is more performant. Unlike `Array.prototype.map()` there is also no return value to `.forEach()` that would allow for further chaining.

It could conceivably be more readable and therefore useful at the end of a call chain (example below), or if each item should be applied to an unknown callback. Those edge cases aside, should it not be avoided?

```
['1', '2', 3].map(Number)
             .forEach(value => sum += value)
```

Comment: @Rooster Since `for...of` is an ES6 feature, questionable browsers don't support either of these options.

Comment: `for of` and `forEach` are about the same thing for the average coder. On the other hand, as usual, no IE support for the `for of` and `for in` loops so I'd avoid those for a while.

Comment: @ssube he asked is there ANY reason, not is there any reason for things that support ecmascript6 :)   Granted, I guess your point may be somewhat implied ;P

Comment: I hardly found any use cases for `forEach` so far (you know, side effects are bad), and it certainly won't be any more useful in ES6.

Answer (score 5):

The most important difference is that you cannot break from a `forEach` without throwing, which is using exceptions for flow control and therefore bad practice.

For an array loop that will always touch every element, `for ... of` and `forEach` are pretty equivalent. However, if you have a loop that is guaranteed to hit every element once, you can probably use `map` or `reduce` in place of any for-each construct and make things More Functional.

Your sum example is a great one for `reduce`. `forEach` is not the best choice, when you can just use:

```
let sum = values.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
```

If you want to pick elements out of an array, you can typically use `filter`. For flow control, `every` and `some` work, with inversion as necessary (as mentioned in the comments).

In general, `forEach` can usually be replaced by a more descriptive and specialized array method, unless you specifically need to cause side effects. `for...of` is very useful with iterable objects, but not always the best choice for arrays.

Comment: Probably not the best choice of example from my side. You are of course right in pointing out that  `reduce()` should be used here.

Comment: For flow control, `.every()` or `.some()` could be used.

Comment: @lyschoening: No, it really shouldn't. If you need custom control flow, use a loop and `break` explicitly. Please don't abuse `every` or `some`.

Comment: @Bergi The documentation for [.forEach() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description) suggests using them for that purpose, that's why I mentioned here as an alternative to throwing an error to break the loop. It's not something I could ever see myself writing.

Comment: @Bergi while you're right that breaking can be better for complex flow, I think every or some as the condition to an if is a very valid use case.

Comment: @ssube: I didn't mean to suggest otherwise :-) But I don't consider using `every`/`some` in a condition to be "flow control" (of the loop)