# Javascript yield from the function nested inside generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This code generates an error:

```
function *giveNumbers() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(item) {
        yield item;
    })
}
```

This is probably because yield is inside a function that is not a generator. Is there an elegant way to overcome this? I mean other than:

```
function *giveNumbers() {
    let list = [1, 2, 3];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        yield list[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This is probably because yield is inside a function that is not a generator.

Yes. You cannot use `yield` from callbacks.

> Is there an elegant way to overcome this?

Depends on the use case. Usually there is zero reason to actually want to `yield` from a callback.

In your case, you want a `for…of` loop, which is superior to `.forEach` in [almost every aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31344516/1048572) anyway:

```
function *giveNumbers() {
    for (let item of [1, 2, 3])
        yield item;
}
```

Comment: Ceterum censeo `forEach` delendam esse a ES6.

Comment: For those of you who do not know Latin (like me) or are too lazy to google-translate: "`forEach` will certainly be wiped out in ES6".

Comment: @Palisand *[Furthermore, I consider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est) that `forEach` must (should) be wiped out as of ES6*

Comment: @Palisand Admittedly, that's at least what I meant, my Latin is a bit rusty and I have no idea whether "a ES6" is the right choice here

Comment: @Bergi - "there is zero reason to actually want to yield from a callback" - reason is to make asynchronous code synchronous.  Why? To make it looks better. Is there some bypass to achieve this?

Comment: @fider You cannot make asynchronous code synchronous, but you can use `await` syntax. [Without `forEach` callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572), at least.

Comment: *My story why this feature would be useful.* I'm trying out a very nice but almost unmaintained package for working with graphs, `ngraph.graph`. Its API exposes only one method for iterating over graph nodes, `forEachNode`, which accepts a callback to be executed for each node. It would be **great** to be able to `yield` a node inside that callback to get an iterator and then use it as one wishes.

Comment: @N.Kudryavtsev Well that feature is impossible, as iterators are lazy but `forEach` is not. Your best bet would be fetching all nodes into an array, and then iterating that - you can easily wrap that in a helper function that returns an iterator. Not very efficient, though. Better patch that package.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `yield *` syntax.

```
function *giveNumbers() {
    yield * [1, 2, 3].map(function(item) {
        return item;
    })
}
```

Comment: this does not yield to parent scope

Answer (score 1):

*yield* returns the result to the caller.
let's assume the `forEach` callback is a generator (it's not a problem to set a costume generator there) - it means tha when the callback `yield` the result - it yields it back to `forEach`.

Basically, in your question what you attemp to do is:

```
callback -> yields to forEach -> yields to giveNumbers -> yields to caller
```

So, `forEach` should yield the result back to `giveNumbers`. but since `forEach` doesn't work like this, it's impossible without re-prototype arrays with costume `forEach`.
Actually, you second snippet *is* the most elegant to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `while` and pass arguments as such ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oLt9x1ke/))

```
function *giveNumbers(array, start) {
    var index = start || 0;
    while(array.length > index + 1) {
        yield array[index++];
    }
    return array[index];
}


var g = giveNumbers([1,2,3], 0);

var finished = false;

while(!finished) {
    var next = g.next();
    console.log(next.value);
    if(next.done) {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's no way to yield directly like with the `.map` example in the other answer. For example, if we have a tree of nodes, and each node has a `traverse` method to traverse the tree, accepting a callback that runs for each node, we can create an additional array to yield:

```js
function nodes(obj) {
  const nodes = []
  obj.traverse(node => nodes.push(node))
  yield * nodes
}

for (const node of nodes(someTree)) console.log(node)
```

If we have access to the array, we can directly loop to avoid an extra array:

```js
function nodes(obj) {
  yield obj
  for (const node of obj.children) {
    yield * nodes(node)
  }
}

for (const node of nodes(someTree)) console.log(node)
```