# Why should forEach be preferred over regular iterators?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I was reading the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). There is a particular statement that says:

> Don’t use iterators. Prefer JavaScript’s higher-order functions instead of loops like for-in or for-of.

The reason they give for the above statement is:

> This enforces our immutable rule. Dealing with pure functions that return values is easier to reason about than side effects.

I could not differentiate between the two coding practices given:

```
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    // bad
    let sum = 0;
    for (let num of numbers) {
     sum += num;
    }
    sum === 15;

    // good
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach((num) => {
     sum += num;
    });

    sum === 15;
```

Could anyone explain, why should `forEach` be preferred over regular `for` loop? How does it really make a difference? Are there any side effects of using the regular `iterators`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This reasoning in Airbnb style guide applies to array methods that are used for immutability, which are `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, etc. but not `forEach`:

> This enforces our immutable rule. Dealing with pure functions that return values is easier to reason about than side effects.

So the comparison is more like:

```
// bad
let sum = 0;
for (let num of numbers) {
 sum += num;
}
sum === 15;

// bad
let sum = 0;
numbers.forEach((num) => {
 sum += num;
});

sum === 15;

// good
const sum = numbers.reduce((num, sum) => sum += num, 0);

sum === 15;
```

Generally, `for > forEach > for..of > for..in` in terms of performance. This relationship is uniform in almost all engines but *may vary for different array lengths*.

`forEach` is the one that was significantly improved in latest Chrome/V8 (almost twice, based on [this](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-forEach) synthetic test):

[image]

[image]

Since all of them are fast, choosing less appropriate loop method just because of performance reasons can be considered preliminary optimization, unless proven otherwise.

The main benefits of `forEach` in comparison with `for..of` is that the former be polyfilled even in ES3 and provides both value and index, while the latter is more readable but should be transpiled in ES5 and lower.

`forEach` has known pitfalls that make it unsuitable in some situations that can be properly handled with `for` or `for..of`:

- callback function creates new context (can be addressed with arrow function)
- doesn't support iterators
- doesn't support generator `yield` and `async..await`
- doesn't provide a proper way to terminate a loop early with `break`

Comment: I did not understand the opening line `This reasoning in Airbnb style guide applies to array methods that are used for immutability, which are filter, map, reduce, etc. but not forEach:` Why `forEach` cannot be used for immutability?

Comment: It can. But it isn't immutable by nature. New value isn't provided for you automatically (like with `reduce` or `map`). You mutate a variable inside loop that was defined elsewhere (`sum` in your example). You could modify existing object the same way and thus break 'immutabile rule' (well, you could do that with `reduce` too, but it's commonly considered a mistake). `for` and `forEach` are equally 'bad', according to this reasoning, the fact that `forEach` has a function doesn't affect anything in this regard, because we can't return the result from this function.

Comment: I consider this reasoning valid (although often prefer `for..of` for readability), but not the conclusions they made. The chapter https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators is contradictory and inconsistent. In one place it states that side effects should be avoided, and then they do side effects inside forEach and label it as 'good'. Remember, it's just style guide. Style guides are opinionated and don't always make sense.

Comment: Unless there's a fundamental reason why some constructs are much harder to optimize for, these kinds of benchmark comparisons are <extremely> brittle. For example, on the most recent v8 version 10.4.123.20 I'm finding that `for...of`, `for`, and `forEach` basically have the same performance.

Comment: Its worth noting that forEach support async and await now.

Comment: @Azur_Was_here Can you clarify? Afaik there's no progress on that

Comment: @EstusFlask use arrow functions for desired functionality
array.forEach(async (element) => {
    await --Functionality
});

Comment: @Azur_Was_here This discards returned promises which defeats the purpose of using them, this is what this remark was about. You can't neither chain them or catch errors from them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @EstusFlask I guess your right in that regard but it will wait out the request to complete then discard the promise.

Answer (score 17):

That makes no sense. `forEach` should never be preferred. Yes, using `map` and `reduce` and `filter` is much cleaner than a loop that uses side effects to manipulate something.

But when you need to use side effects for some reason, then `for … in` and `for … of` are the idiomatic loop constructs. They are easier to read and [just as fast](https://youtu.be/EhpmNyR2Za0?t=17m15s), and emphasise that you have a loop body with side effects in contrast to `forEach` which looks functional with its callback but isn't. Other advantages over `forEach` include that you can use `const` for the iterated element, and can use arbitrary control structures (`return`, [`break`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641347/1048572), `continue`, [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34104231/1048572), [`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572)) in the loop body.

Comment: n.b. Eric Lippert has essentially said the same about `foreach` vs. `.ForEach(...)` in C#: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ Seems like the airbnb people are falling into the pitfall of thinking something that looks functional is preferable just because it looks functional.

Answer (score 3):

The below is a list of advantages I see between the two.

#### Advantages of "for of":

1. In dev-tools, you can see the value of all variables in the function just by hovering. (with `forEach`, you need to change which stack-entry you're in to see variables not accessed within the loop function)
2. Works on all iterables (not just arrays).
3. You can use `break` or `continue` directly, instead of needing to use the `some` function and doing `return true`, which reduces readability. (can be [emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340513/2441655))
4. You can use `await` within the loop, with the async/await context preserved. (can be [emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340513/2441655))
5. Code within the loops can directly return out of the overall function. (can be [emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340513/2441655))

#### Advantages of "forEach"

1. It's a function call like `map` and `filter`, so it's easier to convert between the two.
2. It doesn't need transpilation to be used in pre-es2015 contexts (just needs a simple polyfill). This also means you don't have to deal with odd "error catching" from the transpilation loop, which makes debugging in dev-tools harder. (depends on transpilation tool/options)
3. You can make a "custom forEach" method with added features. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340513/2441655) is a version that adds support for `break`, `continue`, `return`, and even `async`/`await`)
4. It's a bit shorter. (`for-of` is 5 characters more if using `const` -- 3 if using `let`/`var`)

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` **iterations cannot be delayed** by `await`. This means you cannot use `forEach` to pipeline, let's say, web requests to a server.

Also `forEach` is not present on `async Iterables`.

Consider the following cases:

#### 1

```js
let delayed = (value)=>new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 2000));


(async ()=>{
    for(el of ['d','e','f'])console.log(await delayed(el))
    
})();


(async()=>{
    
    ['a','b','c'].forEach(async (el)=>console.log(await delayed(el)))
   
})();
```

Result:

```
d
a
b
c
e
f
```

The elements of `[d,e,f]` array are printed **every two seconds**.

The elements of `[a,b,c]` array are printed **all together after two seconds**.

#### 2

```js
let delayed = (value)=>new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 2000));

async function* toDelayedIterable(array) {
    for(a of array)yield (await delayed(a))    
}


for await(el of toDelayedIterable(['d','e','f']))console.log(el)

toDelayedIterable(['a', 'b', 'c']).forEach(async(el)=>console.log(await el));
```

Result:

```
d
e
f
Uncaught TypeError: toDelayedIterable(...).forEach is not a function
```

The elements of `[d,e,f]` array are **printed every two seconds**.

Error when trying to access `forEach` on the `asyncIterator` of `[a,b,c]` array.

Answer (score 2):

Majority of the time, the Airbnb styleguide tries to keep things consistent. This doesn't mean that there are never reasons to use a for loop or a for-in loop, like suppose you want to break out of the loop out early.

The immutability comes into play when using a for loop to the change the value of something. Like reducing an array to an integer or mapping over elements to generate a new array. Using a built-in `map`, `reduce`, or `filter`, will not directly mutate the array's value directly so it's preferred. Using `forEach` over a for/for-in loop enforces the style consistency of using a higher order function over an iterator, so I believe that's why it's being recommended.

Comment: Could you explain the statement `This isn't the same for forEach` Why would `forEach` mutate the array's value as compared to other methods like `map`, `reduce` , etc.?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't inherently mutate the array's value. I meant that unlike `map` or `filter`, `forEach` will always return `undefined`, it doesn't have a return value and can be used to mutate the array (should have clarified this better). Updated.

Answer (score -2):

see the [Performance of foreach and forloop](https://jsperf.com/foreach-and-for) here

only for readablity we are using foreach.
Other than that for loop is prefered for browser compatibality ,performance and native feel.

Comment: The link that you gave suggests, `forEach` is much faster.

Comment: *"There is no difference"* - He's talking about the V8 engine. That's the difference.  On safari `for` is consistently faster than `foreach`

Comment: @Bergi There is a difference. AIK, for > forEach > for..of > for..in in terms of performance, this is uniform in almost all engines. There's still no parity, you can check it yourself https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach-vs-for-of . Interestingly, forEach is the one that was significantly improved in latest Chrome version.