# Convert an array of objects to array of the objects' values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert this array

```
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];
```

to something like this

```
orders = [
  ['100', 'admin', 'March 6, 2019'],
  ['120', 'admin', 'March 6, 2019'],
  ['80', 'admin', 'March 7, 2019'],
  ['200', 'admin', 'March 7, 2019'],
];
```

and I have read that `Objects.values()` returns the values in an array, so I tried to iterate through the `order` array by using `forEach()` and using the `Object.values` on each item in the array.

```
let newOrders = orders.forEach(order => {
  return Object.values(order);
});
```

I don't know if what I am doing is right and I am new to Javascript. Please help me.

Comment: @reggaeguitar [It has too many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420944/1048572) that you can trip you (like has happened here), [I like `for …of` much better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844413/1048572) and recommend it universally for beginners

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As order of values in array returned by [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) isn't guaranteed, you should consider use of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with some [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). You can then extract object properties in separate variables and return them in desired order explicitly.

```js
const data = [
  { amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  { amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  { amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  { amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' }
];

const result = data.map(({ amount, user, date }) => [amount, user, date]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be mentioned in your `Object destructuring` link, but the order is preserved because variable names are relevant and should match the property names. `const result = data.map(({ date, amount, user }) => [amount, user, date]);` works just as well even though the variable definitions has been modified. This [link](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/) helped me understand.

Answer (score 22):

Using `destructuring`. **Use this if property ordering (of the object) is required in  the output**

```js
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];

console.log(orders.map(({amount,user,date})=>[amount,user,date]))
```

Use `map` and `Object.values` to get the values from the objects. **This does not assure the order in the output will be the same as in the object**  [Refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];
console.log(orders.map(e=>Object.values(e)))
```

Comment: Even simpler `orders.map(Object.values)`

Comment: It's relevant because it means your code could return `['100', 'admin', 'March 6, 2019']` for an order and `['admin', 80', 'March 7, 2019']` for another.

Comment: The spec does not require the order, but apparently all major browsers follow the order anyway.

Comment: @JollyJoker **False.**  I seem to remember that chrome has certain problems, especially when it comes to objects the have numerical keys. It orders it as 1, 111, 1245, 13 instead of 1, 13, 111, 1245.

Comment: @I.Am.A.Guy That's the order in the spec. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/7126740

Comment: The first part of your answer is potentially buggy. Could you please remove it or add at least add a warning? Your answer has been accepted and the question is on "Hot Network Questions", so many people will read it.

Answer (score 22):

The order in which the object's properties are enumerated is not guaranteed ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/87015)). The simplest solution is to explicitly specify the keys in the desired order:

```
let result = orders.map(order => [order.amount, order.user, order.date]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `orders.map(Object.values)`

```js
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];

const result = orders.map(Object.values);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];

const result = orders.map(Object.values);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
orders.map((order) => Object.values(order));
```

`map` will return you a new array, while `forEach` just do callback on each element of array

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution, useful if you have many instances where you have these `struct`-like objects with different orders/keys. A functional approach, `propsToArray` takes a series of keys as individual parameters and returns a function which performs the desired transformation on the objects.

```js
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  {  amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];

// option 1
let propsToArray = function(...keys) {
    return function(obj) {
        return keys.map(key => obj[key]);
    }
};
// option 2
//  propsToArray = (...keys) => (obj) => keys.map(key => obj[key]);

// resulting function
let orderToArray = propsToArray("amount", "user", "date");

console.log(orders.map(orderToArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let orders = [{
    amount: '100',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '120',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '80',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '200',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  },
];

let array = []; //initializing array
orders.forEach((element) => { //using array function for call back
  for (var j in element) { //looping through each element of array
    array.push(element[j]); //pushing each value of object present inside the orders
  }
});
console.log(array); //array is ready
```