# i want to convert array of objects in a particular way

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a scenario while working for charts where i need to convert the below array of objects 
into other array of arrays.

## Inputs

```
const country = [
  {"country": "Germany","visits": "306"},
  {"country": "USA","visits": "106"},
  {"country": "UK","visits": "206"},
];
```

and the desired output should look like below::

```
[
          ["Country", "Visits"],
          ["Germany", 306],
          ["USA", 106],
          ["UK", 206]
]
```

I am unable to get this desired output.

Comment: Simply use `map` on array to transform them: `const output = country.map(c => [c.country, c.visits])`

Comment: Use the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041867/convert-an-array-of-objects-to-array-of-the-objects-values) to get your 2nd, 3rd and 4th arrays. Use the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys) to get the keys  from one of your objects - `country[0]` for example.

Comment: Well i prepared an answer, but when i was ready the question was closed, here is it using reduce...

`const country = [
  { country: 'Germany', visits: '306' },
  { country: 'USA', visits: '106' },
  { country: 'UK', visits: '206' },
];

const reducer = (acc, curr, idx, self) => {
  const result = acc;
  result.push([curr.country, curr.visits])
  if (idx === self.length - 1) {
    const keys = Object.keys(curr);
    result.unshift(keys);
  }
  return result;
}

const result = country.reduce(reducer, [])
console.log(result);`

Comment: Your answer solved my issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is map the fields to an array.

```js
const countries = [
  { "country": "Germany", "visits": "306" },
  { "country": "USA",     "visits": "106" },
  { "country": "UK",      "visits": "206" },
];

console.log(countries.map(country => [ country.country, country.visits ]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want all the values, just use `Object.values`.

```js
const countries = [
  { "country": "Germany", "visits": "306" },
  { "country": "USA",     "visits": "106" },
  { "country": "UK",      "visits": "206" },
];

console.log(countries.map(country => Object.values(country)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```