# How can I remove special characters except this string?

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have a form that is returning a string of visitors names. Returned string looks like this:

```
[{"First Name":"JAMES","Last Name":"SMITH"},{"First Name":"SARAH","Last Name":"SMITH"}]
```

I'm using JavaScript in Zapier to remove the special characters from the string:

```
let INPUT = inputData.INPUT;
let OUTPUT = INPUT.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
output = [{INPUT, OUTPUT}];
```

but that gives me this output:
FirstNameJAMESLastNameSMITHFirstNameSARAHLastNameSMITH

My ultimate goal is to produce something like this:
JAMES SMITH
SARAH SMITH
etc

Is it possible to remove the special characters EXCEPT for the string `},{`? I could then use zapier to split the records using `},{` as the identifier.

Thanks!

Comment: You essentially have an array of objects there. Look into how to parse the object values. It's well covered on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041867/convert-an-array-of-objects-to-array-of-the-objects-values)). Manipulating the string isn't really the right way to do this.

Comment: @jackstrum That is JavaScript....

Comment: @jackstrum The code I posted _is_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I am not terribly familiar with Zapier, but assuming it has basic JavaScript functionality I would be inclined to convert the string to an object and work from there rather than parse it myself or use regular expressions. You can do:

```
let parsedString = JSON.parse(INPUT)
```

Which will give you an object instead of a string. Much easier to work with, and you can loop through it to perform any operations you need to on each visitor:

```js
let parsedString = JSON.parse('[{"First Name":"JAMES","Last Name":"SMITH"},{"First Name":"SARAH","Last Name":"SMITH"}]')

parsedString.forEach(a => {
  console.log(`${a["First Name"]} ${a["Last Name"]}`)
})
```

If you *only* need a string of visitor names separated by a space and don't need to perform any actions on individual visitors, you can do:

```
JSON.parse(str).flatMap(Object.values).join(' ')
```

```js
    console.log( JSON.parse('[{"First Name":"JAMES","Last Name":"SMITH"},{"First Name":"SARAH","Last Name":"SMITH"}]').flatMap(Object.values).join(' ') )
```

As pointed out by Unmitigated

Comment: thanks, this is really useful. I tried the code `code` JSON.parse(str).flatMap(Object.values).join(' ') 
'code' 

and received the error ReferenceError:str is not defined

I believe I need to map the output value from the form to this in some way?

Comment: @jackstrum "str" is a common abbreviation for "string" and is just a placeholder like "John Doe" which you would replace with the name of the variable containing your string. It seems like you're storing the string you want to parse in a variable called "INPUT" so you would use JSON.parse(INPUT).flatMap(Object.values).join(' ') in your case.

Answer (score -1):

How are you?
Here is the code snippet, I just made, according to you requirement.

```js
const data = [
  { "First Name": "JAMES", "Last Name": "SMITH" },
  { "First Name": "SARAH", "Last Name": "SMITH" },
];

const names = data.map((item) =>
  Object.values(item) // only extract values not the keys from object. ["JAMES", "SMITH"] for first item in array.
    .map((e) => e.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, ""))
    .join(" ")
);

console.log(names);
// names
// [ 'JAMES SMITH', 'SARAH SMITH' ]
```

I hope this code works for you.
Thank you.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately the form will always return different visitors names, so I need the code to run on whatever the form returns, so I assume the code cannot contain actual names or it will run unless the names match those in the code lol.

Comment: Can you give me, how the form returns in detail?
Then I can make another code.