# How can I write this function with a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm working on a FreeCodeCamp javascript problem. I was able to write a working function using a for loop, but when I try to write the same function with a forEach loop, it doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

First, the working function:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
        if(name === contacts[i]["firstName"]){
            if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                return contacts[i][prop];
            }
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

The non working forEach function:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    contacts.forEach(function(contact){
        if(name === contact["firstName"]){
            if(contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                return contact[prop];
            }
            return "No such property";
        }
    });
    return "No such contact";
}
```

The array that is being looped through:

```
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
```

];

The problem guidelines:

- We have an array of objects representing different people in our
  contacts lists.
- A lookUpProfile function that takes name and a property (prop) as
  arguments has been pre-written for you.
- The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName
  and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
- If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
- If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such
  contact".
- If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact
  found to match name then return "No such property".

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't, use `forEach`. If you're looking for a better looping syntax, go `for … of`.

Comment: When you `return` from a `for()` loop you return from the parent. When you return from a callback function like the one you pass to `forEach`, you return from that callback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can just use `.filter()` or a `.reduce()`, where you can return a value

Comment: @Mikkel `map` makes no sense here. At best, use `find`.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, my bad, I edited my comment

Comment: @user1538301 I still [recommend avoiding `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420944/1048572) in general, which helps avoiding problems like this here.

Comment: @Bergi that answer is 25% subjective (readability) and 25% arbitary (the const case), I will give you that a `for` loop is typically more performant (no closure) and you can use control statements. The only time I ever use `for` is when I absolutely need to interrupt the loop at some point. I still think to say that one "can't" and "shouldn't" use `forEach` is a bit extreme

Comment: I see. Thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Comment: The answer is use `find()` not forEach since forEach is designed to loop over everything. Other methods like every() and some() are also overlooked when people want to short circuit for each.

Comment: @user1538301 The "can't" was specific to what the OP was trying to do here, where he needs control flow statements.