# Array Map function not able to push Object in simple Example

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ecmascript-6

I got data where in an array I got set of objects (with country and states keys along with values).

Now, I need to format data in such a manner, that I got a new array (with countryName as key, and list of states -in array as values).

I am trying to do that but unsuccessful. Can someone help me out?

```js
var data = [
    {
        "country": "United States",
        "states": [
            "Alabama",
            "Alaska",
            "Arizona",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "states": [
            "Ontario",
            "Saskatchewan",
            "Alberta",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Australia",
        "states": [
            "Australian Capital Territory",
            "Jervis Bay Territory",
            "New South Wales",
            "Queensland",
        ]
    }
];

newData = []; 
data.map(item => newData.push({item.country: item.states});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: That is an improper usage of `map()`.  You use `map()` when you want the result to accumulate translations and return them all in an array to be stored in a variable.  Your instance is not doing that and is simply using it to iterate.  You should use `forEach()` instead.

Comment: ForEach is old and TLs ask to avoid it -- in favor of .map() or .filter();

Comment: Also if you want your keys to have periods in them, you need to quote them, such as `{'item.country': 'my value'}`

Comment: Not sure what age of a function has to do with anything.  It works perfectly fine.  Otherwise, use map properly.

Comment: @Deadpool What is "TLs"? But yes, when you avoid `forEach`, you should also avoid `push`. Use the return value of `map`!

Comment: @Deadpool Surely TLs need a lesson in JS again :) With their logic `for` is even older and should never be used at all

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava There are much better [reasons to avoid `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420944/1048572) than its age.

Answer (score 8):

That because object key with a dot is not a valid syntax. You can resolve this by wrapping the key with `[]`. Also, [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. So, you should either use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method here like:

```
data.forEach(item => newData.push({[item.country]: item.states}));
```

```js
var data=[{country:"United States",states:["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]},{country:"Canada",states:["Ontario","Saskatchewan","Alberta"]},{country:"Australia",states:["Australian Capital Territory","Jervis Bay Territory","New South Wales","Queensland"]}];

var newData = []; 
data.forEach(item => newData.push({[item.country]: item.states}));
console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Or, you can use `.map()` method and simply return the object inside the `.map()` callback and store that in `newData` like:

```
 newData = data.map(item => ({[item.country]: item.states}));
```

```js
var data=[{country:"United States",states:["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]},{country:"Canada",states:["Ontario","Saskatchewan","Alberta"]},{country:"Australia",states:["Australian Capital Territory","Jervis Bay Territory","New South Wales","Queensland"]}]

var newData = data.map(item => ({[item.country]: item.states}));
console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `newData = data.map(item => ({[item.country]: item.states}));` would be the correct use of map.

Answer (score 2):

Correct use of `map` is to return value in map method, which is missing in your code. Apart from that use destructure to further simplify.

```
const newData = data.map(({country, states}) => ({[country]: states}));
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        "country": "United States",
        "states": [
            "Alabama",
            "Alaska",
            "Arizona",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "states": [
            "Ontario",
            "Saskatchewan",
            "Alberta",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Australia",
        "states": [
            "Australian Capital Territory",
            "Jervis Bay Territory",
            "New South Wales",
            "Queensland",
        ]
    }
];

const newData = data.map(({country, states}) => ({[country]: states}));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: 
 It works well with your requirements.

```
data.forEach(item => {
    const obj = new Object();
    obj[item.country] = item.states;
    newData.push(obj)
});
```

Here we are using the `new` keyword to declare our Object and just pushing the object into our Array. Also, since `country` is a variable so we are using the `[]` notation rather than the `dot` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
var data = [
    {
        "country": "United States",
        "states": [
            "Alabama",
            "Alaska",
            "Arizona",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "states": [
            "Ontario",
            "Saskatchewan",
            "Alberta",
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Australia",
        "states": [
            "Australian Capital Territory",
            "Jervis Bay Territory",
            "New South Wales",
            "Queensland",
        ]
    }
];


let newData = data.map(item => { return { [item.country] : [...item.states]}})
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = []
array.forEach(element => {
  arr.push({key:element.country, value: element.state})
}
```

**if you use map then please return but i think you use forEach in such case

Answer (score 0):

please use for loop, for async await condition, map not working well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).