# Convert an array of objects with a unique id property to a Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I have an array of objects, where each object has a unique member called `id`. How do I create a Map where the `id` if the Map's key?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, do you have an example array?.. And what output you expect.

Comment: JSPrefs for the 3 answers below are here: https://jsperf.com/array-to-map-4

Comment: Should be pretty simple. Have you tried it yourself? Please show us your code. What did not work?

Answer (score 8):

You want to reduce your array into a map:

```js
const arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:2}];

const map = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc.set(item.id, item), new Map());

console.log(map.get(1));
```

Here is a [JSPref](https://jsperf.com/array-to-map-4) against using `map` and `forEach`.

In Chrome v53 `reduce` is fastest, then `forEach` with `map` being the slowest.

Comment: Curious to know why this got a down vote. It's not making intermediate arrays which may not be faster (and will bump the garbage collector later)

Comment: @gothdo why complex? Because it uses reduce?

Comment: I'd say for someone reading the code, this is more literate of its intension. Therefore simpler. Unless you don't know what `reduce` is of course.

Comment: Harsh downvote. It may look complex on the surface, but this is simply a pure function with no side-effects and so is easier to reason about.

Comment: @Gothdo haha... to keep it simple

Comment: @Gothdo I've changed it to `const`. (It appears you didn't get the irony)

Comment: @Gothdo I've added a JSPref for my own curiosity. For me this runs 48% faster than using `map`

Comment: with edge, foreach is the fastest, then comes reduce and map.

Comment: Nice. Tbh very little difference on chrome between forEach and reduce on Chrome. It's allocating the arrays rather than called set which is a performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

You could map a new array in the needed format for the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, value: 'one' }, { id: 2, value: 'two' }, { id: 3, value: 'three' }, { id: 4, value: 'four' }, { id: 5, value: 'five' }],
    map = new Map(array.map(a => [a.id, a]));

console.log([...map]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or iterate and add the new item to a certain key

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, value: 'one' }, { id: 2, value: 'two' }, { id: 3, value: 'three' }, { id: 4, value: 'four' }, { id: 5, value: 'five' }],
    map = new Map();

array.forEach(a => map.set(a.id, a));
console.log([...map]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: In ES6 it's better to use for..of loop instead of `forEach()` method, see [Are there reasons to use array.forEach() over for…of, when both could be used, in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31344516/3853934). `forEach()` is also slower than a loop.

Comment: but i do not need an exit of the loop. just iterating.

Comment: But you don't know if someone using this code won't need to modify it to exit the loop. And still it's slower.

Comment: @Gothdo Can't see how `for..of` provides any benefits over `forEach` here. In fact, using `forEach` allows for abstraction into a smaller, reusable method, e.g. `const addToMap = item => map.set(item.id, item); array.forEach(addToMap);`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue If you want to use functional programming with composable methods, you shouldn't use side effects like `set`. So that's hardly an advantage here. At least, use `reduce` instead of `forEach` like in Ross' answer. And really, for imperative iteration (which is what we need here) `for…of` loops are more idiomatic ES6.

Comment: @Bergi Not arguing that a pure function isn't a better choice. Just given this answer there is more benefit to forEach. Being idiomatic ES6 is subjective at best. Abstraction is quantifiable, rightly or wrongly used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the array elements to `[element.id, element]` pairs and then pass the resulting array to the `Map` constructor.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, a: true, b: false}, {id: 2, a: false, b: true}]

const map = new Map(arr.map(element => [element.id, element]))

// Check if map looks OK
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  console.log(key, value)
}
```